# Random Number Calculation Logic

Tags: c, algorithm, random, numbers

I'm looking at someone else's code and trying to figure out the logic behind what they wrote. What would one use the following random number calculation for?

```
return ( ((rand() % 10000)+1) <= Rate * 100);
```

`Rate` here is being used for a user-specified value representing an overall percentage of when a certain event occurs.

Comment: it's a wibbly wobbly timey wimey stuff

Comment: @KarolyHorvath - If you wrote that as an answer instead of a comment, I would be obliged to select it as the one I accept.

Comment: Instead you could as well try to open the door, without trying to understand the War Doctor's screwdriver sub routine. :P

Comment: Actually, Karoly might be right either way, considering RNGs typically use the current time as seed. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left part of the expression returns a random number between 1 and 10,000 (due to the `+ 1`; otherwise it would be between 0 and 9,999).

`Rate` can then be used to determine the effective chance of the expression being `true`. The higher `Rate` is, the higher the chance of returning `true`.

Since `Rate` is multiplied with 100, you're able to determine the `Rate` using 0 to 100 (essentially percentages) with `Rate = 0` never and `Rate = 100` always returning `true`.

Comment: Why compare the range of 1 to 10,000 with a rate of 0 to 100? Wouldn't (rand() % 100)+1) make more sense on the left-hand side of the expression?

Comment: Probably to allow more precision. With the given implementation you've got a resolution of 0.01 % rather than 1 % (assuming `Rate` is a float or double value). Keep in mind that the modulo operator `%` won't understand how to handle floating point numbers.

Comment: Doctor -- Not necessarily.  If rand returns numbers between (say) 0 and 32767, then rand%100 is slightly more likely to be <=67 than it is to be >67.

Comment: Hm... true. I guess it's a cheaper way to circumvent that predictability (more likely to be less than 67) without involving multiplication and division.

Comment: Thinking about it, this might not be the case (so more likely just for precision). Otherwise left shifting would probably be better than multiplication with a non-power of two number.

Answer (score 2):

To generate a random integer between 1 and 10000 inclusive. As for the comparison with `Rate*100` who can say as you do not specify what this means.